# PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and remove parameter value

Tags: php

This is my PHP so far:

```
parse_str(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $queries);

if($queries['is_search'] == 'Y') {
    var_dump('Yes');
} else {
    var_dump('No');
}

if(empty($_GET['redirect'])) {
    fn_redirect("cart.cart_list&sort_by=date&sort_order=desc&redirect=true");
} elseif($queries['is_search'] == 'Y') {
    fn_redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

What I am wanting to do is search the `HTTP_REFERER` and then remove the param "redirect" so it does not fire the previous redirect condition, is this possible?

`var_dump` when the fn_redirect is done shows:

> string(67) "/admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list" string(2) "No"

When use search form on page which sets params to return to cart.cart_list. I need to remove true from redirect so does not redirect again and will display the search results

> string(222) "/admin.php?is_search=Y&cname=&email=james%40rebootdigital.co.uk&total_from=&total_to=&dispatch%5Bcart.cart_list%5D=Search&period=A&time_from=&time_to=&users_type=A&p_ids=&hint_new_view=Name" string(3) "Yes"

Looking at it, the REFERER does not have it but I need to use something from it or add redirect=false or something to stop it looping.

Comment: dont base anything important on HTTP_REFERER it is unreliable

Comment: what would you suggest? im trying to hack around a controller in the software as no hooks to attach to, so need to redirect on initial load to set softby etc.. maybe i might just remove search form...